# Responsive Design - Two divs next to each other, one fixed and one fluid

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have two divs next to each other, on the left is a static box which is about 50x50px with a content box on the right which is about 50x200px. I do not know how much content will be in the right div, could be 20 words or could be 50, it depends on the comment.

I want the right div to have a min width of 50 but to start at 200 and for the height to be auto, However I want to to stay aligned to the right of the left div.

Because I do not know how much content is in the right div I am a little stumped, I would usually make the left div have a 100% height, in this case it isn't going to work. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm ok ill try to figure something out. one thing i noticed was; a min width of 50 but starting at 200? Why would you still have a min width of 50 then?

Comment: I have a little trouble undestanding, what you want: Both divs left and right are supposed to have equal height of max 50px? Or is the height flexible, as well, depending on the content of the right div?

Comment: `display: table;` on the parent and `display: table-cell;` on the children.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, both divs start at same height but as the right div collapses it will need to get taller without jumping below the left div. i hope that clarifies better.